# Else part I don't want to capture nothing in Ternary Operation in Python

Tags: python

I have tried with short program to print list items whose length greater than 2.

```
def mygenerator(func,*args):
       for arg in args:
            for item in arg:
                yield func(item)
print(list(mygenerator(lambda x: x if x.__len__()> 2 else None ,['ab', 'abc', 'aba', 'xyz', '1991'])))
```

It is not solved not purpose I capture none in my list when condition is failed.

Output :- [None, 'abc', 'aba', 'xyz', '1991']

I know with filter I can do that operation but what is missing in my generator:-

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x if x.__len__()> 2 else None ,['ab', 'abc', 'aba', 'xyz', '1991'])))
```

Could you please guide me what I needs to modify. How can I use Ternary Operation without else.

Comment: Small nitpick but `len(x)` is preferred over `x.__len__()`

Comment: write normal function instead of lambda and use normal `if`

Comment: eventually you could put all in `filter(None, your list)` and it should remove `None` (but also  empty strings and `0` and everything what gives False when you use `bool()`

Comment: Yup, I know that filter will help me but it is not solved my purpose

Comment: The callable / lambda / function you pass into `filter` is expected to be a predicate, which means it returns a boolean (True or False). The filter will retain items for which the predicate returns True, and it will purge items for which the predicate returns False. The predicate should not be returning `x` or `None`.

Comment: The only way to do what you ask is to change `yield func(item)` to `f = func(item)` / `if f:` / `yield f`.  What you've written there is a very odd construct.  Your generator yields every result it gets, and there's no way to have a lambda not return anything.

Comment: ok bool() function is work

Comment: @Tim Roberts ,you solution is also great

Comment: You've reinvented map when you're trying to reinvent filter

Comment: Yes ..... Mr. Ted Brownlow...thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use normal `filter()` and return `True` or `False`

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x)> 2 ,['ab', 'abc', 'aba', 'xyz', '1991'])))
```

OR use list comprehension with `if` at the end

```
print( [x for x in ['ab', 'abc', 'aba', 'xyz', '1991'] if len(x) > 2] )
```

---

**EDIT**

Your generator with `if` inside function (but this recreates `filter`)

```
def mygenerator(func, *args):
    for arg in args:
        for item in arg:
            if func(item):
                yield item

print(list(mygenerator(lambda x: len(x) > 2, ['ab', 'abc', 'aba', 'xyz', '1991'])))
```

Comment: def mygenerator(func,*args):
    for arg in args:
        for item in arg:
            f = func(item)
            if f:
                 yield func(item)....It will work

Comment: maybe it will work but you can do it without creating own function - you recreated `filter`

Comment: Yes, Mr. furas .....I can do that...